# Cardinality of a Cartesian product

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If the set $S$ has cardinality $\#S$ and the set $T$ has cardinality $\#T$, what is the cardinality
of $S \times T$?

The value of $\#T$ and $\#S$ are unknown, so how is this possible?

In my case the cardinality is $2$ if you just substitute those letters....

Comment: You’re not being asked for a number: you’re being asked what $\#(S\times T)$ is in terms of $\#S$ and $\#T$. That is, knowing $\#S$ and $\#T$, how could you calculate $\#(S\times T)$?

Comment: $S = \{ a,b,c,d \}$ and $T= \{ 1,2,3 \}$. So, $\# S = 4$ and $\# T = 3 $. Just write the set $S \times T$ and count the number of elements of $S \times T$. Try to guess the answer.

Comment: where did you get S={a,b,c,d} and T={1,2,3} from?

Comment: Im not given any values.......

Comment: #A*#B or if they are infinite then I believe usually it is the larger one, or it stays the same after cartesian with a same cardinality set.

Comment: @GuledYGwoopz: ThePortakal simply picked those sets as examples. More generally, the suggestion is that you try a few specific examples with small sets $S$ and $T$, writing out and counting the members of $S\times T$. If you do this correctly with several examples, you should be able to spot the simple relationship between the number $\#(S\times T)$, on the one hand, and the numbers $\#S$ and $\#T$ on the the other.

Comment: @Matthew: Given the discrete mathematics tag, it’s unlikely that the question is about infinite sets. However, the correct answer for finite sets also applies to infinite sets, so it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: You would have to define multiplication on infinite cardinalities, no?

Comment: @Matthew: Multiplication of infinite cardinalities is well-known. (And yes, the product of two infinite cardinals is the same as their sum, namely, the maximum of the two.)

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ and $T$ are finite sets:

$S \times T = \{ (s,t) : s \in S, t \in T \}$
There are $\text{#S} \cdot \text{#T}$ elements in this set: think about how many ways there are of choosing a pair: there are $\text{#S}$ possibilities from $S$ and $\text{#T}$ possibilities from $T$.